# Detecting radio wakeup on android

Tags: android

is there anyway to detect or be notified of when the radio is being woken up on an Android device?

Comment: What radio are you referring to?

Comment: I am referring to cellular connectivity

Comment: And by "woken up", do you mean changing power states, whether or not we are in airplane mode, or something else?

Comment: Sorry I meant for example the transition from being in a state where data is being sent/received to a state when the radio is not exchanging data and vise versa

Comment: AFAIK, there's no system broadcast for that, as it would happen too frequently.

Comment: He means the cellular can be on 1 of 3 states: full power, half power, and off. Full power last around 60 seconds past the last request and takes a good bit of battery. I assume he wants to batch out some files when the radio is already at full power instead of waking it and causing more battery drain.

Comment: Yes exactly, would there be anyway of doing that?